# Identifying Coordinate System of dataset

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I have an `.nt` file that contain some geographical information like the flowing:

`<'Ain_Daoura>   <hasGeometry>   "POINT (186.01667 213.88333)"^^<degrees> .`.

After loading the data into Virtuoso and trying to run the flowing function `bif:st_geomfromtext("POINT (186.01667 213.88333)")` I get the following error:

> The point coordinates are spherical degrees
> and the latitude is out of range -90..90

I think that the data is in different coordinate system and I couldn't find out how to transform it to the supported coordinate system.

This information may help: coordinates of "'Ain_Daoura" on Google Maps is @33.8117406,2.8459543

Comment: Obviously, there isn't a 186 or 213 N or S. Your best solution is to go back to your data source and ask them.

Comment: By chance, subtracting 180 to the coordinates seems to render near the correct location in Algeria. Perhaps some weird unconventional system was used and the degrees wrap around the globe differently... But better check with the data provider to be certain.

Comment: @FSimardGIS Indeed inverting the coordinates and subtracting 180 seems to give the write coordinates. I did check with many data points and it work. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @FSimardGIS Please add the solution as an answer

Comment: @HansErren Done

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting 180° to the coordinates seemed to resolve the issue and the points rendered at the correct location in Algeria.

Perhaps some weird unconventional system was used and the degrees wrapped around the globe differently.